# How to add array items to imported model(interface) in Angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript

Below is my model and I want to create a request as shown below.

```
 export interface   IItemFlow
    {
        itemId : number;
        itemName:string;

    }

    export class ISaveItemFlowRequest {
        itemFlowRequest:IItemFlow[];
        userId:number;
    }
```

Imported model in component.ts

```
import { ISaveItemFlowRequest, IItemFlow} from "../item/model/Iitemflowfile"
```

Save button click adding items into model by using push() .

```
   this._saveItemFlowRequest.itemFlowRequest.push({itemId:101;itemName:'ABC'});
```

**Error: Cannot read property 'itemFlowRequest' of undefined**

My request should generate as follows.

```
{
  "itemFlowRequest": [
    {

      "itemId": 1,"itemName":"ABC"
    },
    {

      "itemId": 2,"itemName":"xyz"
    }
  ],
  "userId": 22
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the `this._saveItemFlowRequest`;

```
this._saveItemFlowRequest: ISaveItemFlowRequest  = {itemFlowRequest : [], userId: null}
this._saveItemFlowRequest.itemFlowRequest.push({itemId:101;itemName:'ABC'});
```

Another aproach is create a class with a constructor that implements `ISaveItemFlowRequest`